# How to store individual images user selected from gallery?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to allow user's to upload multiple images from gallery, and the code below does this, but what if I want to access each image that was uploaded and store them inside different variables? I figure I could do something listed below, but I find this to be inefficient, because if the user uploads more than 3 images, then the app crashes due to a null exception.. I would like to be able to allow the user to upload x amount of images, and simply store them all inside individual variables, what would be the best approach of doing this?

```
  //opens gallery to allow user to choose multiple images..
public void openGallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);


}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount(); //evaluate the count before the for loop --- otherwise, the count is evaluated every loop.
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    //Uri imageUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    selectedImageUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(0).getUri();
                    uriTwo = data.getClipData().getItemAt(1).getUri();
                    uriThree = data.getClipData().getItemAt(2).getUri();

                    Log.i("image1", selectedImageUri.toString());
                    Log.i("image2", uriTwo.toString());
                    Log.i("image3", uriThree.toString());


                    Glide
                            .with(getContext())
                            .load(selectedImageUri)
                            .fitCenter()
                            .into(chosenProductImage);

                }
            }
        } else if (data.getData() != null) {
            String imagePath = data.getData().getPath();
            Log.i("dataa", imagePath);
            //do something with the image (save it to some directory or whatever you need to do with it here)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with storing an image in a variable.

Comment: And where are you uploading the chosen images too? To a server on the internet?

Comment: I am uploading it to a server, and like what I did in the for loop for the onActivityResult method.                      selectedImageUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(0).getUri();  I stored the first image that was selected in this variable. I Would like to do this for all the images....

Comment: You call that storing an image in a variable. Confusing. All what happens is assigning the first uri to an uri variable. Then the other uries to the same variable.